# duvida quanto a variavel session_start()

Tags: php, mysqli

Eu coloquei o método `session_start()` para fazer com que o nome do utilizador apareça na tela quando ele fizer o login nas paginas seguintes, mas eu queria colocar o "nome" dele em vez do "email" segue o código que eu fiz:

Código para validar a entrada do usuário.

```
<?php 

session_start();

require_once("conexao.php");

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die ( mysqli_error() );

mysqli_select_db($conn, 'projeto') or die ( mysqli_error() );

$user = $_POST['email'];
$pwd = $_POST['senha'];


$query = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM nutricionista WHERE email = '$user' AND senha ='$pwd'"));

if($query == 1){
    $_SESSION['email'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $pwd;

    header("location: menuNutricionista.php");
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Dados informados incorretamente!');history.back();</script>";
}

?>
```

Aqui já é a pagina *HTML* aonde vai aparece `bem-vindo + nome do usuário`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../css/script.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagens/favicon.png" />  

    <?php  

    session_start();

    if((!isset ($_SESSION['email']) == true) and (!isset ($_SESSION['senha']) == true))
    {
    unset($_SESSION['email']);
    unset($_SESSION['senha']);
    header('location:index.php');
    }

    $logado = $_SESSION['email'];
    ?>

</head>
<body>
    <img id="emblema" src="../imagens/emblema.png">

    <div class="div-logado">
        <?php echo"Bem-vindo </br>$logado "; ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom se não for pra mexer muito no seu código, creio que você só vai precisar criar uma nova query que lhe traga um array.

Faça:

```
$query2 = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM nutricionista WHERE email = '$user' AND senha ='$pwd'"));
```

Então defina na SESSION o array do usuario. Exemplo:

```
$_SESSION['nome'] = $nome
```

Isso claro, contando que no seu Banco de Dados já exista uma coluna "nome". Substitua pelo nome correto que está na sua tabela.

Na sua página HTML você pode substituir a linha que define o usuario logado por:
$logado = $_SESSION['nome'];

E na chamada para mostrar o nome do usuário pode usar o $logado mesmo.

Não lembro se a chamada do mysqli está correta, se não der certo me avisa que reescrevo aqui de novo.

Answer (score 1):

Ignorando todos os problemas, que existem pelo menos quatro, você deve fazer uma nova query para pegar essas informações, supondo que você tenha a informação do `nome` salva em alguma coluna do banco de dados, relacionado ao e-mail.

```
<?php  

session_start();

// Se não houver as informações você encerra a página e redireciona
if(!isset($_SESSION['email'], $_SESSION['senha'])) {
     unset($_SESSION['email'], $_SESSION['senha']);
     session_destroy();

     header('Location: index.php');
     exit();
}

$email = $_SESSION['email'];

// Havendo a sessão você busca o nome
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, 'SELECT nome FROM nutricionista WHERE email = ?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $logado);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

?>
```

Isto tem o mesmo principio que fez na outra página, na primeira. Selecionamos o `nome` (supondo que este seja o nome da coluna do MySQL) onde houver o `email` igual ao da sessão, definimos o e-mail em `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` para que ele seja o valor do primeiro `?` da nossa query.

Depois, o resultado no nome será definido em `$logado`, como indicamos em `mysqli_stmt_bind_result`.

Então para exibir você utiliza:

```
<div class="div-logado">
    Bem vindo <br>
    <?= htmlentities($logado, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8'); ?>
</div>
```

---

No método de "segurança vai com deus", você pode também usar:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT nome FROM nutricionista WHERE email = "'. $_SESSION['email'] .'"');

list($logado) = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
```

Que é exatamente o mesmo que você fez na primeira página.